# What is an example of a field, that is not a sigma-field?

Tags: measure-theory

What is an example of a field, that is not a $\sigma$-field?
I read a $\sigma$-field requires closure of it's elements (which are sets) under countable unions, countable intersection, and complement; and a field only requires closure under finite unions, finite intersections, and complement.

Comment: For an explicit example, start with the collection of all intervals in $\mathbb R$ of the form $(a,b]$, $(-\infty,b]$, or $(a,\infty)$. The set of all finite unions of such intervals, along with $\mathbb R$ and $\emptyset$, is a field, but it is not a $\sigma$-field, since for example, $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a,b-1/n] = (a,b)$, which is not in the field.

Comment: The above comment helped me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A field is closed under finite operations. For example take the field generated by open sets $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}$. By definition, this will include all finite intersections, unions, complements, etc of such sets. Then such a field will never contain a single point, say $\{0\}$, since you'd need an infinite intersection of open sets to generate it.

Comment: How would that point be generated?

Comment: x = [x,x]= $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}$(x-1\n, x+1\n)?

Comment: @user0: yes that works.

Comment: One typo: I think $(a,b)\subset \mathbb R$ is better notation?

Answer (score 6):

Fix an infinite set $X$, and define $\scr{F}$ to be the set of $E\subset X$ for which either $E$ or $X\setminus E$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Another example of a field, that is more complicated but also important: the $\bf \Sigma^0_\lambda$ sets for any limit ordinal $\lambda$.

Recall: the $\bf \Sigma^0_1$ sets are the open sets, the $\bf \Sigma^0_{\alpha+1}$ sets are the sets which can be written as a countable union of complements of $\bf \Sigma^0_\alpha$ sets, and a set is $\bf \Sigma^0_\lambda$ ($\lambda$ limit) if it is $\bf \Sigma^0_\alpha$ for some $\alpha<\lambda$. In the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, $\bf \Sigma^0_{\omega_1}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field containing every open sets - that is, the $\bf \Sigma^0_{\omega_1}$ sets are the **Borel sets**.

However, even though (in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$) the $\bf \Sigma^0_\alpha$ sets do not form a $\sigma$-field for any $\alpha<\omega_1,$ there are *lots* of ordinals $\alpha<\omega_1$ for which the $\bf \Sigma^0_\alpha$ sets *do* form a field - namely, the limit ordinals.

Note that even the smallest of these - the set of $\bf \Sigma^0_\omega$ sets - is still significantly larger than the field described in Alex's answer above. So don't think of these as "small" examples; rather, think of them as *natural* examples of fields which arise in the process of trying to build a $\sigma$-field "from below".